# how to exit from all the activities(including resuming activities)

Tags: android

I have 4 activities. First one is splash activity and second is main menu activity and third activity is specific option from main activity and fourth one is result of third activity. I am using the `noHistory="true"` for second activity in manifest file. I have exit option in option menu for all activity. Once I exit from first three activity in app again I open app means it going launching application (there no resuming activities) but when I was exit from fourth activity then again I will open app means it show third activity instead of launch the app.

Exit code in option menu is

```
flag_activity_clear_top
flag_activity_no_history
```

but the previous activity is not close. **How can we exit from all activities (including resuming activity)?**

If I use the `noHistory="true"` attribute for third activity means it working properly, but when I press the home screen then again I reopen app it show splash activity instead of resuming activity. So I avoid to use the `noHistory` attribute in third activity.

Kindly please give solution for exit from all activities.

Comment: when you going to next activity, just finish current activity.

Comment: thanks for your reply sir.In any activity i have exit option in option menu.if i am exit from Third activity means there is no problem.it exit as usual and i open app again it is starts from the begin.When we exit from the Fourth activity again i reopen the app from launcher it open third activity(resume activity).I want exit from all the activity(including resuming activity)

Answer (score 0):

using Intent

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FirstActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.putExtra("FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP", true);
    startActivity(intent);
```

added in OnCreate your All Activity

```
if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP", false)) {
    finish();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply redAllocator.I will check and come back to your sir

Comment: Hi red allocator.Actually i am not going to firstActivity instead of that i am exit from  the all the activity.Once i pressing the exit button(i didnot want to go for the first activity) i want exit from all the activity.

Answer (score 0):

Use sharePreference  and check the value inside shared preference (inside onResume or OnStart()) every time you launch the application and navigate accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply sonal balekai.Kindly please post the example for using sharePreference(exit from all activity)

Comment: you can go through this link to understand about Sharepreference in android                                                 https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

Comment: Thanks for reply sonal balekai.

Answer (score 0):

To close all Activities you can try call

`finishAffinity();`

This method finish current activity as well as all activities immediately below it in the current task that have the same affinity.

finishAffinity() can be called from Context i.e (Activity, Service etc)
If every time you close the application you want to close all Activities you just have to call finishAffinity in your `OnDestroy()` method or in `onClick`  like

```
@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        finishAffinity();
    }
```

or

```
finishButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finishAffinity();
        }
    });
```

Also example for `menu`

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.exit_item) {
        finishAffinity();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

And you should NOT use any Flags for start or close an Activity, just call `finishAffinity()` where you wanna exit from application and finish all activities.

In this video you can see how it works https://youtu.be/L5w8mhB9aNk

Comment: Thanks for your reply Vlad Pylyp.I will check and come back to you  sir

Comment: while i using the finishAffinity(); it show some "error"

Comment: please post sample code or reference link for using the finishAffinity();

Comment: @jaykumar  I'v updated my answer. See it, there you'll find right way ))

Comment: Thanks for your reply sir.Here after only i going to try. sir

Comment: @jaykumar So your problem is fixed? Am i right? Accept your answer if so

Comment: First activity have "noHistory" in andriod XML file so if i resume app and then reopen app means it is from beginning of application.Here there is no problem.I have exit option in option menu(of the second activity) through these if i exit from app and reopen the app it is from begining of app(Here also there  is no problem).But we are facing problem in third activity only.If i exit app(exit option in option menu) from third activity and reopen the app it show the second activity instead of begining of the app.Here i want to display the first activity only but it show only second activity only

Comment: My point of view each time we are using the exit option is only for exit from particular activity.If i open second activity from first .Here first activity have (noHistory) in XML.So right now i am in second activity then exit from app(second act only closed).Then reopen app it is from begining of the app(second act is closed then resuming only the first act).But the first act have noHistory in XML.So thats why the app is open from begining of the app.My query is if i exit from third act it is not open the second act.why it is show second activity means it didnot have noHistory in XML.

Comment: Please providing the solution for these problem.If i exit from any activity and again reopen app means it is from begining of the app only.it is not show resuming activity

Comment: So, my solution should work fine. As you can see from the video i attached i've got 3 activity. I close any of them from menu( or on button click). After i open application it always starts from begin.  
Or i don't understand what do you want?